# Best way to fin days between dates in same column (MS Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query that pulls dates from >16 million records based on an ID number. This generates about 800 records with ID and ScanDate fields, sorted oldest to newest. Each ID can have multiple entries. What is the best way to get the differences between dates?

I can pretty easily export to Excel and get it that way, but the boss wants it automated and turned into a final report. I'm not strictly opposed to doing that in Excel, but keeping it in Access would be best for our use.

I have tried this way, but it just hangs and crashes Access.

```
SELECT  LenelID,
        ScanDate,
        NextDate,
        DATEDIFF("D", ScanDate, NextDate)
FROM    (   SELECT  LenelID, 
                    ScanDate,
                    (   SELECT  MIN(ScanDate) 
                        FROM    qry_Filtered_access T2
                        WHERE   T2.LenelID = T1.LenelID
                        AND     T2.ScanDate > T1.ScanDate
                    ) AS NextDate
            FROM    qry_Filtered_access T1
        ) AS T
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking this up into 3 separate queries?

Comment: Where is the `Where Condition` that trims 16M to 800 rows?

Answer (score 0):

For only 800 records, the best and simplest method by far is simply to open the records as a *recordset*, and then loop through this collecting the date differences. No fancy SQL is needed.

These could either be fed to a collection or written to another (temp) table with the other data you will need for the report.

Comment: It sounds like it's pulling the 800 records out of the massive data set.  Recordset might be fine for working with the resulting 800 records, but getting to that point you'll want a SQL query as it will have better performance.

Comment: @Chaosbydesign: Sure. Pull the 800 records via SQL. It is the 800 you will loop.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, for best performance, I should think about pulling via SQL, writing to a temp table, and looping through the temp table recordset with VBA to get a datediff column? Then export that to a report?

Comment: @DFoster25: Almost ... use the table as _recordsource_ for the report.